# How to align the ul li list like a table using css?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a `ul li` list and I have to show it as a table. I tried the below code but I am getting some issues in alignment.

I am getting output like this. How can I fix the alignment?

**Note**: I can't use the table.

[image]

```css
.tableMemberRow ul li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.tableMemberList-header {
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.tableMemberList-row {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tableMemberList-row .nameEmail p {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.tableMemberList-row .nameCircle {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.tableMemberList-row .nameCircle p {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.tableMemberList-row .nameCircle p span {
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
}

.tableMemberList-row div {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="tableMemberList">
  <div class="tableMemberRow">
    <ul>
      <li class="tableMemberList-header">
        <div>Flat No.</div>
        <div>Member</div>
        <div>Mobile</div>
        <div>Location</div>
        <div>Status One</div>
        <div>Status Two</div>
      </li>
      <li class="tableMemberList-row">
        <div data-label="Flat No.">101</div>
        <div data-label="Member">
          <div class="d-table membername">
            <div class="nameCircle d-table-cell">
              <p><span>S</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="nameEmail d-table-cell">
              <p>jhad ajsdkba</p><span>daskd@gmail.com</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div data-label="Mobile">(467) 637-1234</div>
        <div data-label="Location">990</div>
        <div data-label="Status One">Ok</div>
        <div data-label="Status Two">No</div>
      </li>
      <li class="tableMemberList-row">
        <div data-label="Flat No.">102</div>
        <div data-label="Member">
          <div class="d-table membername">
            <div class="nameCircle d-table-cell">
              <p><span>S</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="nameEmail d-table-cell">
              <p>asdlasdl</p><span>jadjkaskjd@gmail.com</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div data-label="Mobile">(467) 637-1234</div>
        <div data-label="Location">990</div>
        <div data-label="Status One">Ok</div>
        <div data-label="Status Two">Yes</div>
      </li>
      <li class="tableMemberList-row">
        <div data-label="Flat No.">103</div>
        <div data-label="Member">
          <div class="d-table membername">
            <div class="nameCircle d-table-cell">
              <p><span>S</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="nameEmail d-table-cell">
              <p>alkalsdlas</p><span>asdasldlaksjd@gmail.com</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div data-label="Mobile">(467) 637-1234</div>
        <div data-label="Location">990</div>
        <div data-label="Status One">Ok</div>
        <div data-label="Status Two">No</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can use external library, check out bootstrap or equivalent. In there, you'll find the class col-[1-12] and row. Those two classes makes it easy to create grid/table layout rapidely. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/

Comment: What issues are you having with alignment? What result are you going for? Indeed, I see you are using bootstrap, why not use their classes to build this?

Comment: @prettyInPink, I have to show like table output, Check my li's are not aligned with header

Comment: I know the bootstrap grid but I have to use using li

Comment: ```li.tableMemberList-row > div {flex: 1;}``` and ```li.tableMemberList-header > div {flex: 1;}```

Comment: The values in each cell are not the same width, so the alignment will be different. There is no easy way to align them without a load of JS.

Comment: I advise you to use a grid.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov, You mean bootstrap grid?

Comment: No. It is not necessary to use bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

This will align, not sure it's this you're after though.

This will give a fixed width `calc(100% / 6)` to those flex children.

```css
.tableMemberRow ul li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tableMemberRow ul li > div {
  width: calc(100% / 6);
  word-break: break-word;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: .5rem;
}

.tableMemberList-header {
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.tableMemberList-row {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tableMemberList-row .nameEmail p {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.tableMemberList-row .nameCircle {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.tableMemberList-row .nameCircle p {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.tableMemberList-row .nameCircle p span {
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
}

.tableMemberList-row div {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="tableMemberList">
  <div class="tableMemberRow">
    <ul>
      <li class="tableMemberList-header">
        <div>Flat No.</div>
        <div>Member</div>
        <div>Mobile</div>
        <div>Location</div>
        <div>Status One</div>
        <div>Status Two</div>
      </li>
      <li class="tableMemberList-row">
        <div data-label="Flat No.">101</div>
        <div data-label="Member">
          <div class="d-table membername">
            <div class="nameCircle d-table-cell">
              <p><span>S</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="nameEmail d-table-cell">
              <p>jhad ajsdkba</p><span>daskd@gmail.com</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div data-label="Mobile">(467) 637-1234</div>
        <div data-label="Location">990</div>
        <div data-label="Status One">Ok</div>
        <div data-label="Status Two">No</div>
      </li>
      <li class="tableMemberList-row">
        <div data-label="Flat No.">102</div>
        <div data-label="Member">
          <div class="d-table membername">
            <div class="nameCircle d-table-cell">
              <p><span>S</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="nameEmail d-table-cell">
              <p>asdlasdl</p><span>jadjkaskjd@gmail.com</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div data-label="Mobile">(467) 637-1234</div>
        <div data-label="Location">990</div>
        <div data-label="Status One">Ok</div>
        <div data-label="Status Two">Yes</div>
      </li>
      <li class="tableMemberList-row">
        <div data-label="Flat No.">103</div>
        <div data-label="Member">
          <div class="d-table membername">
            <div class="nameCircle d-table-cell">
              <p><span>S</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="nameEmail d-table-cell">
              <p>alkalsdlas</p><span>asdasldlaksjd@gmail.com</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div data-label="Mobile">(467) 637-1234</div>
        <div data-label="Location">990</div>
        <div data-label="Status One">Ok</div>
        <div data-label="Status Two">No</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check your answer and implement it with mine.

Comment: Did this help in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to refactor both `css` and `html` a little. Check if this works for you:

```css
.tableMemberRow {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.header_1 {
  width: 10%;
}

.header_2 {
  width: 30%;
}

.content_1 {
  width: 10%;
}

.content_2 {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content_3 {
  width: 30%;
}

.tableMemberList-header {
  display: flex;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  text-align: center;
}

.tableMemberList-row {
  display: flex;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.tableMemberList-row .nameEmail p {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.tableMemberList-row .nameCircle {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.tableMemberList-row .nameCircle p {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.tableMemberList-row .nameCircle p span {
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
}

/* .tableMemberList-row div {
  text-align: left;
} */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="tableMemberRow">
  <ul>
    <li class="tableMemberList-header">
      <div class="header_1">Flat No.</div>
      <div class="header_2">Member</div>
      <div class="header_2">Mobile</div>
      <div class="header_1">Location</div>
      <div class="header_1">Status One</div>
      <div class="header_1">Status Two</div>
    </li>
    <li class="tableMemberList-row">
      <div class="content_1" data-label="Flat No.">101</div>
      <div class="content_2" data-label="Member">
        <div class="nameCircle d-table-cell">
          <p><span>S</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="nameEmail d-table-cell">
          <p>jhad ajsdkba</p><span>daskd@gmail.com</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content_3" data-label="Mobile">(467) 637-1234</div>
      <div class="content_1" data-label="Location">990</div>
      <div class="content_1" data-label="Status One">Ok</div>
      <div class="content_1" data-label="Status Two">No</div>
    </li>
    <li class="tableMemberList-row">
      <div class="content_1" data-label="Flat No.">102</div>
      <div class="content_2" data-label="Member">
        <div class="nameCircle d-table-cell">
          <p><span>S</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="nameEmail d-table-cell">
          <p>asdlasdl</p><span>jadjkaskjd@gmail.com</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content_3" data-label="Mobile">(467) 637-1234</div>
      <div class="content_1" data-label="Location">990</div>
      <div class="content_1" data-label="Status One">Ok</div>
      <div class="content_1" data-label="Status Two">Yes</div>
    </li>
    <li class="tableMemberList-row">
      <div class="content_1" data-label="Flat No.">103</div>
      <div class="content_2" data-label="Member">
        <div class="d-table membername">
          <div class="nameCircle d-table-cell">
            <p><span>S</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="nameEmail d-table-cell">
            <p>alkalsdlas</p><span>asdasldlaksjd@gmail.com</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content_3" data-label="Mobile">(467) 637-1234</div>
      <div class="content_1" data-label="Location">990</div>
      <div class="content_1" data-label="Status One">Ok</div>
      <div class="content_1" data-label="Status Two">No</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```